# How do I edit IDA Pro function xrefs?

Tags: reverse-engineering, reverse, ida

IDA is very persistent in its mislabeling of a function call I'm making (it's hand-written assembler, but I've verified it in a debugger). It was working before, but as I've been patching in new code to the existing db using python, it seems to have gone a bit wonky.

Now, even though it acknowledges I'm pushing function_a to eax, it insists that my subsequent call eax is a call to function_b. No matter how I try to "refresh" it, it persists. I've tried deleting the function, undefining and redefining the section, even calling DelCodeXref (this last method seems to remove it from the function xrefs list, but the comments still appear next to the call and if i undefine/redefine, it naturally just reappears).

The only fix seems to be writing in a second mov eax, offset function_a above it, but it's hardly elegant to throw in a redundant instruction just to be rid of a misleading comment. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: you should post some text that demonstrates what you mean. I am familiar with IDA, but I am not 100% what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this with Alt-F11 ?  - that runs the callee plugin.

this plugin is installed in the ida plugins directory by default.